# How to place click to display dropdown instead of hover

Tags: css, html

Hi am using bootstrap 4 i have developed menu bar. In that menu bar it has categories like LAPTOP,MOBILES,CAMERA etc. when user click menu it will display the products based on that category.

My doubt was  i have tried to implement transition effect in **LAPTOP**.But first i tried in hover effect it was working fine but by requirement was when i click the menu then only it should display the products with transition effect. so please tell me how to achieve it.

Alternatively instead of hover i have tried focus and checked but it doesn't work.

```
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    height:166px;
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 1600px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    height:166px;
}



 .nav-link-type-one {
      color: white !important;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 26px;
      width: 185px;
      height: 51px;
      text-align: center;
  }

  .nav-link-type-one:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link-type-one {
      color: #ec7f4a !important;
      text-decoration: none
  }

  .bg-dark-type-one {
      background-color: #232323 !important;
  }

  .nav-link-type-one {
      position: relative;
  }

  .nav-link-type-one::after {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      margin-right: -21px;
      margin-top: -7%;
      background-image: url('../../../../assets/icons/Path247.svg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      transform: rotate(136deg);
      content: '';
  }

  li.show .nav-link-type-one::after {
      background-image: url('../../../../assets/icons/Path244.svg');
      transform: rotate(226deg);
      margin-top: -3%;
  }

  /* hover effect for 1 Dropdown */

  .dropdown-hover-one-effect:hover {
      outline: 2px solid #ec7f4a;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav *ngIf="bg_color == 'black' && color == 'orange' " class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark-type-one">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
    aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

      <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-org">

        <a class="nav-link-type-one nav-org " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          LAPTOP
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-content" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://ssl-product-images.www8-hp.com/digmedialib/prodimg/lowres/c05962448.png" alt="">
                    <h6> HP</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://images.idgesg.net/images/article/2017/11/bestbuylenovolaptop-100742402-large.jpg">
                    <h6> Samsung</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://www.lenovo.com/medias/lenovo-laptop-legion-y520-15-front.png?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wyNzI1M3xpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2hiMS9oMDQvOTQxMjY3NTUwMjExMC5wbmd8YjYxMzUxYzUwZDcyNmEyYjJmN2Y1MmQyZTAxYmI4NmY5Yjg4N2Y0ZjIxMWI0YzYyMTM3YTBiZmMyYjZjZGY4Ng">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Sony</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src=" https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/6/4/10180946/u_10180946.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Acer</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE2ygZJ?ver=948e&q=90&m=6&h=623&w=767&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&f=jpg&o=t&aim=true"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Lenovo</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link-type-one " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          SPEAKERS
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-second" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUgsHZFrUhLko1Eyed-z_Pwwjg4FqiO9qnJ6uUnVGiqjWBNXlX"
                      alt="">
                    <h6> Jass</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeX49tLv6J6I6B77_eam9ZIKTMuTbv15AVJo_T1swI-Azx0xwN">
                    <h6> Samsung</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1cNK.dPoIL1JjSZFyq6zFBpXal/Selfie-Mini-Bluetooth-Speaker-for-Phone-Portable-Wireless-Speaker-Sound-Bluetooth-Handsfree-Cute-Catoon-Rabbit-Cat.jpg_640x640.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Sony</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://image.made-in-china.com/43f34j00lmAEJKdLdwoq/LED-Bluetooth-Speaker-Portable-Wireless-Speakers-Musical-Audio-Hand-Free-Subwoofer-Loudspeakers-for-Phone-with-Mic-TF-USB-FM.jpg"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> senizer</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-um6op5fe4t/images/stencil/500x659/products/2419/1615/Wireless_Bluetooth_Mini_Speaker_with_led_light_blue2__61739.1499074394.jpg?c=2"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> skulcandy</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link-type-one " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          MOBILES
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-third " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://images.samsung.com/is/image/samsung/p5/global/mkt/unpacked201802/pcdpfs/smartphone-galaxy-star-type2.png?$ORIGIN_PNG$"
                      alt="">
                    <h6> samsung</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://teja10.kuikr.com/i5/20171228/VB201705171774173-ak_LWBP1579145809-1514461108.jpeg">
                    <h6> Huawei</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://assets.mspcdn.net/t_c-desktop-normal,f_auto,q_auto,d_c:noimage.jpg/c/11918-55-1.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Sony</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://img.tatacliq.com/images/i3/252Wx374H/MP000000003623987_252Wx374H_20190111195404.jpeg"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> VIVO</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://4.imimg.com/data4/LL/LL/GLADMIN-/in-resources-8fda3511-a61f-4c26-a4a0-f2bd37049878-images-productimages-29679821-500x500.jpg"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Iphone 6</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          CAMERA
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-four" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/468c23968de175daa7458ece997663ac-320-80.jpg" alt="">
                    <h6> Sony</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRGibGMgRaDelhbNeXcTkUlH1c4yvAtF9oRiM9hP5yjIxzSeP3fUA">
                    <h6> Nikon</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQA51gnFEIgRWiIT3Y3Qi7gZSIYJ0e43c8x5uUKtVm8jv6Qx8xE">
                  </div>
                  <h6> lumix</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRunxpvSx04BfYa9J-axgB8c5BI6_lvzxRlYRzRfDS0-Bb6xM7q"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Canon</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPI0UfP9Cyn5EC9zKpi_JYduD0DARvGGe8k9ov__LeEQf12dpl"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Winait</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          DESKTOP
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-five" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://media.hpshopping.in/catalog/product/cache/c58b88357feb47e1e90e0994b7c41391/4/1/41vrhct2ypl_3.jpg"
                      alt="">
                    <h6> HP</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://media.hpshopping.in/catalog/product/cache/c58b88357feb47e1e90e0994b7c41391/4/E/4EB09AA-1_T1539236227.png">
                    <h6> Samsung</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/jm9hfgw0/allinone-desktop/n/q/w/lenovo-aio-520-22iku-original-imaf97e7bfu9cwjy.jpeg?q=70                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Sony</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://ssl-product-images.www8-hp.com/digmedialib/prodimg/lowres/c05282390.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Acer</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://www.lenovo.com/medias/lenovo-thinkcentre-m710-tw-gallery1.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w0NTQ4MHxpbWFnZS9qcGVnfGltYWdlcy9oYWYvaDU4Lzk0MDU4OTI3NTU0ODYuanBnfDA2NTg4MTU2NDAyYmE0NmYxYzhhNDAxMWIzNjQzZjc2MDI5NjQ2NWZiNmJlOTcxNmQzYWM4MDIwYmZmZjEzNDc"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Lenovo</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Pendrive
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-six" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/704/704/pendrive/7/z/g/sandisk-cruzer-blade-16-gb-original-imad4dyumyqy3b4y.jpeg?q=70"
                      alt="">
                    <h6> sandisk</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51bm1Ll%2BeNL._SX425_.jpg">
                    <h6> hp</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="http://img.fkcdn.com/image/pendrive/p/z/y/sony-usm64x-b-400x400-imaehyjcgqzkxjbu.jpeg">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Sony</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src=" https://img.staticbg.com/thumb/large/oaupload/banggood/images/09/ED/db329437-4b26-4a19-9665-d9f191796397.jpg"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> eagit</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://cdn.buysnip.com/IBALL-64GB-OTG-HYBRID-Pendrive-01.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> iball</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          TABLET
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-seven" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5PDfCILgeEMDtkdLPrgSVJNBlbMIfPZA_88m2bfMKZ6dzuB5BiQ"
                      alt="">
                    <h6> HP</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnuE-NXyW0xl9Xy4sxNl0myPommcDqPDvF5B2SMGQ-e6PlwmSQ">
                    <h6> Samsung</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTii2lqE4xqlxqwu3rA2ymwZI_To_xq3MOpBJ2dQt9LSaHvXav1">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Sony</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQpXQH2sSOatJ8mOemEI2OBvhHBzDcu8CkHLWDB_Ksp2dvTwvU7xQ"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Acer</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRScLPakgoPm_--CwGtjrhFFr0Mn93005H2Qjfz9TI9LmIiz-o"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Lenovo</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          HEADSET
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-eight" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://multimedia.bbycastatic.ca/multimedia/products/500x500/118/11800/11800872.jpg"
                      alt="">
                    <h6> HP</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://www.astrogaming.com/dw/image/v2/AALZ_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_AstroGaming_RP/default/dwd035ce5e/product-images/A10-939-001706-Zelda-left-micup.png?sw=720&sh=720&sm=fit">
                    <h6> Samsung</h6>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_d50fce48-336a-4979-9423-4c8a2d8ba0f4?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Sony</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img src=" https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/6/4/10180946/u_10180946.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Acer</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src="https://www.lenovo.com/medias/GXD0L03745-main-v1.png?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8NDY2MzM0fGltYWdlL3BuZ3xoMTQvaDA1Lzk0ODgzOTYxNTY5NTgucG5nfDNhOGQ3MGQ1M2QyNDlkOWY5MGUxZjgxZWE2NGIxZjYzZjQxMjFiZGY2N2ZlODA2NjE0OGJlZjI0NjFiZTY4NTk"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h6> Lenovo</h6>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Do you require the solution to be using angular?

Comment: No if can adjusted using css means it will be fine

Comment: I'm sure we don't need *all* of your HTML page, can you reduce this to a more workable, smaller example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap collapse instead of the dropdown menu as this comes with a transition. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

```css
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 1600px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.nav-link-type-one {
  color: white !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  width: 185px;
  height: 51px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link-type-one:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link-type-one {
  color: #ec7f4a !important;
  text-decoration: none
}

.bg-dark-type-one {
  background-color: #232323 !important;
}

.nav-link-type-one {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link-type-one::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: -21px;
  margin-top: -7%;
  background-image: url('../../../../assets/icons/Path247.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: rotate(136deg);
  content: '';
}

li.show .nav-link-type-one::after {
  background-image: url('../../../../assets/icons/Path244.svg');
  transform: rotate(226deg);
  margin-top: -3%;
}


/* hover effect for 1 Dropdown */

.dropdown-hover-one-effect:hover {
  outline: 2px solid #ec7f4a;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <nav *ngIf="bg_color == 'black' && color == 'orange' " class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark-type-one">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-org">

          <a class="nav-link-type-one nav-org " type="btn" href="#collapseExample" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="collapse" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          LAPTOP
        </a>
          <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://ssl-product-images.www8-hp.com/digmedialib/prodimg/lowres/c05962448.png" alt="">
                      <h6> HP</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://images.idgesg.net/images/article/2017/11/bestbuylenovolaptop-100742402-large.jpg">
                      <h6> Samsung</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://www.lenovo.com/medias/lenovo-laptop-legion-y520-15-front.png?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wyNzI1M3xpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2hiMS9oMDQvOTQxMjY3NTUwMjExMC5wbmd8YjYxMzUxYzUwZDcyNmEyYjJmN2Y1MmQyZTAxYmI4NmY5Yjg4N2Y0ZjIxMWI0YzYyMTM3YTBiZmMyYjZjZGY4Ng">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Sony</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src=" https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/6/4/10180946/u_10180946.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Acer</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE2ygZJ?ver=948e&q=90&m=6&h=623&w=767&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&f=jpg&o=t&aim=true" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Lenovo</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link-type-one " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          SPEAKERS
        </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-second" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUgsHZFrUhLko1Eyed-z_Pwwjg4FqiO9qnJ6uUnVGiqjWBNXlX" alt="">
                      <h6> Jass</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeX49tLv6J6I6B77_eam9ZIKTMuTbv15AVJo_T1swI-Azx0xwN">
                      <h6> Samsung</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1cNK.dPoIL1JjSZFyq6zFBpXal/Selfie-Mini-Bluetooth-Speaker-for-Phone-Portable-Wireless-Speaker-Sound-Bluetooth-Handsfree-Cute-Catoon-Rabbit-Cat.jpg_640x640.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Sony</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://image.made-in-china.com/43f34j00lmAEJKdLdwoq/LED-Bluetooth-Speaker-Portable-Wireless-Speakers-Musical-Audio-Hand-Free-Subwoofer-Loudspeakers-for-Phone-with-Mic-TF-USB-FM.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> senizer</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-um6op5fe4t/images/stencil/500x659/products/2419/1615/Wireless_Bluetooth_Mini_Speaker_with_led_light_blue2__61739.1499074394.jpg?c=2" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> skulcandy</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link-type-one " type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          MOBILES
        </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-third " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://images.samsung.com/is/image/samsung/p5/global/mkt/unpacked201802/pcdpfs/smartphone-galaxy-star-type2.png?$ORIGIN_PNG$" alt="">
                      <h6> samsung</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://teja10.kuikr.com/i5/20171228/VB201705171774173-ak_LWBP1579145809-1514461108.jpeg">
                      <h6> Huawei</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://assets.mspcdn.net/t_c-desktop-normal,f_auto,q_auto,d_c:noimage.jpg/c/11918-55-1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Sony</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://img.tatacliq.com/images/i3/252Wx374H/MP000000003623987_252Wx374H_20190111195404.jpeg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> VIVO</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://4.imimg.com/data4/LL/LL/GLADMIN-/in-resources-8fda3511-a61f-4c26-a4a0-f2bd37049878-images-productimages-29679821-500x500.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Iphone 6</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          CAMERA
        </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-four" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/468c23968de175daa7458ece997663ac-320-80.jpg" alt="">
                      <h6> Sony</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRGibGMgRaDelhbNeXcTkUlH1c4yvAtF9oRiM9hP5yjIxzSeP3fUA">
                      <h6> Nikon</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQA51gnFEIgRWiIT3Y3Qi7gZSIYJ0e43c8x5uUKtVm8jv6Qx8xE">
                    </div>
                    <h6> lumix</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRunxpvSx04BfYa9J-axgB8c5BI6_lvzxRlYRzRfDS0-Bb6xM7q" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Canon</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPI0UfP9Cyn5EC9zKpi_JYduD0DARvGGe8k9ov__LeEQf12dpl" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Winait</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          DESKTOP
        </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-five" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://media.hpshopping.in/catalog/product/cache/c58b88357feb47e1e90e0994b7c41391/4/1/41vrhct2ypl_3.jpg" alt="">
                      <h6> HP</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://media.hpshopping.in/catalog/product/cache/c58b88357feb47e1e90e0994b7c41391/4/E/4EB09AA-1_T1539236227.png">
                      <h6> Samsung</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/jm9hfgw0/allinone-desktop/n/q/w/lenovo-aio-520-22iku-original-imaf97e7bfu9cwjy.jpeg?q=70                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Sony</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://ssl-product-images.www8-hp.com/digmedialib/prodimg/lowres/c05282390.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Acer</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://www.lenovo.com/medias/lenovo-thinkcentre-m710-tw-gallery1.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w0NTQ4MHxpbWFnZS9qcGVnfGltYWdlcy9oYWYvaDU4Lzk0MDU4OTI3NTU0ODYuanBnfDA2NTg4MTU2NDAyYmE0NmYxYzhhNDAxMWIzNjQzZjc2MDI5NjQ2NWZiNmJlOTcxNmQzYWM4MDIwYmZmZjEzNDc"
                        alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Lenovo</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Pendrive
        </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-six" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/704/704/pendrive/7/z/g/sandisk-cruzer-blade-16-gb-original-imad4dyumyqy3b4y.jpeg?q=70" alt="">
                      <h6> sandisk</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51bm1Ll%2BeNL._SX425_.jpg">
                      <h6> hp</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="http://img.fkcdn.com/image/pendrive/p/z/y/sony-usm64x-b-400x400-imaehyjcgqzkxjbu.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Sony</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src=" https://img.staticbg.com/thumb/large/oaupload/banggood/images/09/ED/db329437-4b26-4a19-9665-d9f191796397.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> eagit</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://cdn.buysnip.com/IBALL-64GB-OTG-HYBRID-Pendrive-01.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> iball</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          TABLET
        </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-seven" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5PDfCILgeEMDtkdLPrgSVJNBlbMIfPZA_88m2bfMKZ6dzuB5BiQ" alt="">
                      <h6> HP</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnuE-NXyW0xl9Xy4sxNl0myPommcDqPDvF5B2SMGQ-e6PlwmSQ">
                      <h6> Samsung</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTii2lqE4xqlxqwu3rA2ymwZI_To_xq3MOpBJ2dQt9LSaHvXav1">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Sony</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQpXQH2sSOatJ8mOemEI2OBvhHBzDcu8CkHLWDB_Ksp2dvTwvU7xQ" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Acer</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRScLPakgoPm_--CwGtjrhFFr0Mn93005H2Qjfz9TI9LmIiz-o" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Lenovo</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link-type-one" type="btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          HEADSET
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-eight" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://multimedia.bbycastatic.ca/multimedia/products/500x500/118/11800/11800872.jpg" alt="">
                      <h6> HP</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect dropdown-images" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://www.astrogaming.com/dw/image/v2/AALZ_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_AstroGaming_RP/default/dwd035ce5e/product-images/A10-939-001706-Zelda-left-micup.png?sw=720&sh=720&sm=fit">
                      <h6> Samsung</h6>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_d50fce48-336a-4979-9423-4c8a2d8ba0f4?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Sony</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src=" https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/6/4/10180946/u_10180946.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Acer</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-hover-one-effect" href="#">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://www.lenovo.com/medias/GXD0L03745-main-v1.png?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8NDY2MzM0fGltYWdlL3BuZ3xoMTQvaDA1Lzk0ODgzOTYxNTY5NTgucG5nfDNhOGQ3MGQ1M2QyNDlkOWY5MGUxZjgxZWE2NGIxZjYzZjQxMjFiZGY2N2ZlODA2NjE0OGJlZjI0NjFiZTY4NTk" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h6> Lenovo</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```